# How to enforce SCA security with Stripe v3 library payment form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, stripe-payments

I have this code to accept payments on Stripe.
When I use the version of the Stripe v2 library it works, but it fails me in the payments in which I need the reinforced SCA security.
When I change and put the version of the Stripe v3 library, the pay button doesn't work for me.
Could you please tell me what is wrong with the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Stripe - Payment Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-formhelpers.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrapValidator.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-side-notes.css" />
<style type="text/css">
.col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
    margin-right:-4px;
}
.row-centered {
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-right: 9px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-formhelpers-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrapValidator-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#payment-form').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'Wrong Wrong valuealue',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
                    // createToken returns immediately - the supplied callback submits the form if there are no errors
                    Stripe.card.createToken({
                        number: $('.card-number').val(),
                        cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
                        exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
                        exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val(),
            name: $('.card-holder-name').val(),
            address_line1: $('.address').val(),
            address_city: $('.city').val(),
            address_zip: $('.zip').val(),
            address_state: $('.state').val(),
            address_country: $('.country').val()
                    }, stripeResponseHandler);
                    return false; // submit from callback
        },
        fields: {
            street: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The street is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 96,
                        message: 'The street must be more than 6 and less than 96 characters long'
                    }
                }
            },
            city: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The city is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            zip: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The zip is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        max: 9,
                        message: 'The zip must be more than 3 and less than 9 characters long'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 65,
                        message: 'The email must be more than 6 and less than 65 characters long'
                    }
                }
            },
            cardholdername: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Name'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 70,
                        message: 'The name must be between 6 and 70 characters in length'
                    }
                }
            },
            cardnumber: {
        selector: '#cardnumber',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Card Number'
                    },
                    creditCard: {
                        message: 'Wrong card number'
                    },
                }
            },
            expMonth: {
                selector: '[data-stripe="exp-month"]',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Required month'
                    },
                    digits: {
                        message: 'Only Numbers'
                    },
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Expired',
                        callback: function(value, validator) {
                            value = parseInt(value, 10);
                            var year         = validator.getFieldElements('expYear').val(),
                                currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1,
                                currentYear  = new Date().getFullYear();
                            if (value < 0 || value > 12) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            if (year == '') {
                                return true;
                            }
                            year = parseInt(year, 10);
                            if (year > currentYear || (year == currentYear && value > currentMonth)) {
                                validator.updateStatus('expYear', 'VALID');
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            expYear: {
                selector: '[data-stripe="exp-year"]',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Required Year'
                    },
                    digits: {
                        message: 'Only Numbers'
                    },
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Expired',
                        callback: function(value, validator) {
                            value = parseInt(value, 10);
                            var month        = validator.getFieldElements('expMonth').val(),
                                currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1,
                                currentYear  = new Date().getFullYear();
                            if (value < currentYear || value > currentYear + 100) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            if (month == '') {
                                return false;
                            }
                            month = parseInt(month, 10);
                            if (value > currentYear || (value == currentYear && month > currentMonth)) {
                                validator.updateStatus('expMonth', 'VALID');
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            cvv: {
        selector: '#cvv',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Required CVV'
                    },
                    cvv: {
                        message: 'Wrong CVV',
                        creditCardField: 'cardnumber'
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            // this identifies your website in the createToken call below
            Stripe.setPublishableKey('aqui iria el pk_live');
 
            function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    // re-enable the submit button
                    $('.submit-button').removeAttr("disabled");
                    // show hidden div
                    document.getElementById('a_x200').style.display = 'block';
                    // show the errors on the form
                    $(".payment-errors").html(response.error.message);
                } else {
                    var form$ = $("#payment-form");
                    // token contains id, last4, and card type
                    var token = response['id'];
                    // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                    form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "' />");
                    // and submit
                    form$.get(0).submit();
                }
            }
 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row row-centered">
    <img src="img/feg-header.png" class="img-responsive">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <div class="page-header">
    <!-- <img src="img/logo_stripe.png" class="img-responsive"><img src="img/candado.png" class="img-rounded"> -->
      <img src="img/log-feg-snatii.png" class="img-responsive">
    <!-- <h2 align="center">Formulario de Pago</h2> -->
    <!--<h3 align="center">IVE Consultores</h3>-->
  </div>
  <noscript>
  <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">
    <h4>JavaScript is not active!</h4>
    <p>This payment form requires your browser to have JavaScript enabled. Please enable JavaScript and reload this page. Go to <a href="http://enable-javascript.com" target="_blank">enable-javascript.com</a> for more information.</p>
  </div>
  </noscript>
  <?php
require 'lib/Stripe.php';

$error = '';
$success = '';
      
if ($_POST) {
  Stripe::setApiKey("aqui va el sk_live");

  try {
    if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
      throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
    Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => $_POST['total'],
                                "currency" => "eur",
                                "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                                "description" => $_POST['email']));
    $success = 'Correct';
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = ' '.$e->getMessage();
  }
}
?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="a_x200" style="display: none;"> <strong>Error!</strong> <span class="payment-errors"></span> </div>
  <span class="payment-success">
  <?php
  //$success="ok";
  //$asa = "ok";
  //$aa= "<a href=pepe?idc=".$asa.">aqui</a>";
  $aa = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\"><strong>CORRECT: </strong><a href=pagina-exito.php?t=".$token."&p=".$origen."> <strong>IMPORTANT. CLICK HERE</strong></a> to finish the purchase process and return to the FEG page.</div>";
  //echo $success.$aa;
  if($success != "")
  {
      //$aa= 1;
      //echo $success." <a href='pepe?idc='".$aa.">aqui</a>";
      $control = 1;
      echo $aa;
  }
  ?>
  <?php
  $aa1 = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"><strong>Error!</strong> ".$error." <a href=pagina-error.php?t=".$token."&p=".$origen."> CLICK HERE</a> to return to the FEG page</div>";
  if($error != "")
  {
      $control = 1;
      echo $aa1;
  }
  ?>
  </span>
  <fieldset>
  
  <!-- Form Name -->
  <legend>Details of payment</legend>

  <!-- Email -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="65" value="<?php echo $email1; ?>" class="email form-control" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="hidden" name="total" maxlength="65" value="<?php echo $tot; ?>" class="email form-control" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Total Payment</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="importe" maxlength="65" value="<?php echo $subt_f.' €'; ?>" class="email form-control" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>

  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
      <?php
      if($control == 0)
      {
      ?>
    <legend>Card Details</legend>
    
    <!-- Card Holder Name -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"  for="textinput">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="cardholdername" maxlength="70" placeholder="Name" class="card-holder-name form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Card Number -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Card Number</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" id="cardnumber" maxlength="19" placeholder="Card number" class="card-number form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Expiry-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Date</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-inline">
          <select name="select2" data-stripe="exp-month" class="card-expiry-month stripe-sensitive required form-control">
            <option value="01" selected="selected">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="06">06</option>
            <option value="07">07</option>
            <option value="08">08</option>
            <option value="09">09</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
          </select>
          <span> / </span>
          <select name="select2" data-stripe="exp-year" class="card-expiry-year stripe-sensitive required form-control">
          </select>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var select = $(".card-expiry-year"),
            year = new Date().getFullYear();
 
            for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                select.append($("<option value='"+(i + year)+"' "+(i === 0 ? "selected" : "")+">"+(i + year)+"</option>"))
            }
        </script> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- CVV -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">CVV/CVV2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" id="cvv" placeholder="CVV" maxlength="4" class="card-cvc form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Submit -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <center>
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Pay</button>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <br>
      <img src="img/powered_by_stripe@2x.png" class="img-rounded">
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

With version 2 of the Stripe library it works, but it doesn't ask me for the reinforced SCA

When I put version 3 the pay button doesn't work.

Comment: Your code is using an old integration, and you can't fix it by just changing Stripe.js from v2 to v3. You should use PaymentIntent and the Payment Element, as explained in this up-to-date guide: [link](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements).